# Как использовать переданный в функцию аргумент при использовании селектора?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если несложно, скажите, как можно вставить аргумент в селектор?

Ситуация такая: есть функция, которая принимает и создает элемент внутри элемента. При этом id внутреннего элемента будет меняться item1, item2, item3... и т.д., проходя через цикл.

Возможно на примере будет яснее:

Как есть в исполняемом состоянии,но, увы, без приема аргумента (id = item) -

```
  function createElementsInside() {
    $("#bb-bookblock").append("<div class='bb-item' id = 'item1'>1 блок</div>");
    $("#bb-bookblock").children("#item1").append("<div class='content'>Контент</div>");
    }
```

Хотелось бы так

```
var itemId = 'item1';

function createElementsInside(itemId) {

  $("#bb-bookblock").append("<div class='bb-item' id = itemId >1 блок</div>");
  $("#bb-bookblock").children( itemId ).append("<div class='content'> Контент</div>");

}
```

Comment: шаблонные строки с обратными кавычками(кавычки в коммент не вставить)``<div class='bb-item' id = ${itemId} >1 блок</div>``

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: [Я про эти кавычки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Ясно, если это кавычки на тильду, то это трагично, ибо у меня там смена языка. Но ладно, подумаю, что с этим делать завтра, может сменю сочетание смены, хотя, думаю, лучше переопределить через key manager на что-то более приземленное, не находящееся на задворках галактики. 
У меня уже поздно. Если и у Вас, то желаю спокойной ночи

Comment: _у меня там смена языка(с)_ ха-ха, у меня смена на правом **Ctrl**, ибо больше привык к левому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var itemId = 'item1';

function createElementsInside(itemId) {
  $("#bb-bookblock").append("<div class='bb-item' id='" + itemId + "'>1 блок</div>");
  $("#bb-bookblock").children("#" + itemId).append("<div class='content'> Контент</div>");
}
```

Comment: Мр, благодарю, именно то, что мне нужно было

Comment: Я бы поставила +, но мне говорят, что мой маргинальный статус не позволяет этого сделать, пока у меня не будет 15 репутации. Но как только, уверяю Вас, я мигом сюда вернусь, чтобы справедливость восторжествовала

Comment: @Настенька Спасибо :)